# Why does this code work in Python on my desktop but doesn't work in Zapier?

Tags: python, zapier

I've run into a problem with Zapier where this code works fine in Python on my computer, but always throws an error in zapier.  I'm hoping it is something easy so that I can get this sorted out quickly.

```
import requests
import base64

response = requests.get('https://prstvod.s3.amazonaws.com/PursuitUP/PUR86083A_AWS.VTT')
response.raise_for_status() # optional but good practice in case the call fails!
output = response.text
#print (output)
output =  base64.b64encode(output)

#print (output)

url = "https://api.zype.com/videos/5d5c1b165577de355513e24e/subtitles?api_key=NsaCqjERym-vYTa6OiF97Bk9A1BzM6DHYa3SFS8TXPSR6Q78ChQZskFA0RZ2ZT7C"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = '{"subtitle":{"language":"English","extension_type":"vtt","file":"'+output+'"}}'
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

output = response.text

print (output)
```

Comment: what error is it throwing Alex?

Comment: Please provide the error it is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things here.

**Python Specific**
I'm surprised this didn't raise an error on your computer, but `b64encode` takes a bytes object. The `response.text` function returns a decode string object.

**Zapier Specific**
In Zapier, `output` must be set as a dictionary. The `output = response.text` line sets it as a string.

Try the following code:

```
import requests
import base64

response = requests.get('https://prstvod.s3.amazonaws.com/PursuitUP/PUR86083A_AWS.VTT')
response.raise_for_status() # optional but good practice in case the call fails!
output = response.content
#print (output)
output =  base64.b64encode(output)

#print (output)

url = "https://api.zype.com/videos/5d5c1b165577de355513e24e/subtitles?api_key=NsaCqjERym-vYTa6OiF97Bk9A1BzM6DHYa3SFS8TXPSR6Q78ChQZskFA0RZ2ZT7C"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
payload = '{"subtitle":{"language":"English","extension_type":"vtt","file":"'+str(output)+'"}}'
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

output = {'response': response.text}

print (output)
```

**Tip**: You can use the json argument in requests call rather than building your own manually. It would look like:

```
payload = {"subtitle":{"language":"English","extension_type":"vtt","file":str(output)}}
response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```